# Why cant i set the onTouchListener for my RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to make a basic app in which you touch the screen and it changes the background color of the screen.  However I can't set the OnTouchListener for the RelativeLayout that is containing my app essentials.  The app throws an error upon building and then crashes, not sure whats going on here =/  If anyone could help that would be great =)

Java Code:

```
public class ColorCrazeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

int pointCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);
    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
            new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                    if (m.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        changeColor();
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            }
    );

    setContentView(myLayout);
}

public void changeColor(){
    int myNum1 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));
    int myNum2 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));
    int myNum3 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));

    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

    RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);

    myTextView.setText("RGB(" + Integer.toString(myNum1) + ", " + Integer.toString(myNum2) + ", " + Integer.toString(myNum3) + ")");
    myRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, myNum1, myNum2, myNum3));
    addPoints();
}

public void addPoints(){
    pointCount += 1;

    TextView myTextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);
    myTextView1.setText(Integer.toString(pointCount));
}
```

}

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout"
tools:context="com.toymakersdev.colorcraze.ColorCrazeActivity"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="#000c65">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView1"
        android:text="Taps: 0"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:text="Tap here"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have a RelativeLayout nested inside of another RelativeLayout because i thought the error was because it was the root view originally.  Apparently not considering its still throwing the error.

Comment: have you tried `findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){..}`?

Comment: i just tried it didnt change anything =/

Comment: what is the "error"? Please post your stack trace

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnTouchListener(android.view.View$OnTouchListener)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.toymakersdev.colorcraze.ColorCrazeActivity.onCreate(ColorCrazeActivity.java:38)

Comment: Are you sure this layout is setting via `setContentView()` of the Activity (or `inflater.inflate(...)` for fragment)? Beside, you should not call `android:onClick="changeColor"`, this can trigger a merging issue between `onClick()` method and `onTouchListener()`. Try to remove the `onClick` attribute in xml.

Comment: I removed the onclick in the xml and it is still not working.  i have edited the XML above as i did in my code

Comment: One thing that did work was creating a relativelayout dynamically in java code but i dont want to do that because of the amount of code it takes to actually create additional views within that layout.  not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set first the setContentView before do something with it:

For example:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.myLayout); //name of the layout file
}
```

Your activity looks now like this:

```
public class ColorCrazeActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

int pointCount = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.id.myLayout); //name of the layout file

    RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);
   myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
        new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                if (m.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    changeColor();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
);


   }

public void changeColor(){
int myNum1 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));
int myNum2 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));
int myNum3 = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (255));

TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

RelativeLayout myRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);

myTextView.setText("RGB(" + Integer.toString(myNum1) + ", " + Integer.toString(myNum2) + ", " + Integer.toString(myNum3) + ")");
myRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, myNum1, myNum2, myNum3));
addPoints();
   }

public void addPoints(){
    pointCount += 1;

    TextView myTextView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);
    myTextView1.setText(Integer.toString(pointCount));
}
```

Comment: I tried this an its still giving the error =/

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.toymakersdev.colorcraze.ColorCrazeActivity.onCreate(ColorCrazeActivity.java:38)

Line 38 being "myLayout.setOnClickListener(this);"

Comment: @theBeastiest1398 Ok, can you you edit your post and insert the whole activity? And did you change setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); to the name of your layout file?

Comment: I have edited the java section of my code to include the entire activity

Comment: ok that will  not work change setContentView(myLayout); in to setContentView(R.layout.myLayout); myLayout must be the name of the XML file and move that line to under super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: @theBeastiest1398 see the Update

Comment: you must do setContentView(R.id.name_of the_file) what the name is of your XML file

Comment: Yes that solved my problem thank you =)!  I ended up with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_craze);

        RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);
        myLayout.setOnTouchListener(...);`

Answer (score 2):

Set the content view before accessing the layout

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);//adjust this xml layout

RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);
myLayout.setOnTouchListener(
        new RelativeLayout.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                if (m.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    changeColor();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
);
```

If you don't do this first, your activity has no idea where to find the view.

Comment: I tried this but i had to change it around due to scope issues and i ended up with this:
`RelativeLayout myLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout1);

        setContentView(myLayout);

        myLayout.setOnTouchListener(...);`

Comment: the scope issue is because you use `setContentView(myLayout);` while it should be the `layout.xml` file like this `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);`  thats the way you should do it. because your xml file can contain different views